# How do you write nested routes after dynamic path in React Router v5.2?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to write a route that uses a dynamic path and then add an additional parameter after that. The problem is it's being ignored and not rendering my component. As an example the following code works.

```
<Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} component={CaseView} />}
<Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/notifications`}><NotificationsView /></Route>
```

However, the following doesn't work. This will render the CaseView component in the previous example. This should render the `<Sars />` component, but it gets ignored.

Update:

```
                    {caseManagement
                      && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} exact component={CaseView} />}
                    {caseManagement
                      && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases`}><CasesView /></Route>}
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/notifications`}><NotificationsView /></Route>
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/audit`}><AuditView /></Route>
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars`} component={Sars} /> 
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/settings`}><SettingsView /></Route>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is just a route ordering issue. I see you are rendering `` path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} `` *before* `` path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars`} ``. Remember that when using the `Switch` component that it renders ***the first*** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. `"/cases/:caseToken"` is less specific than `"/cases/:caseToken/sars"` so it matches more URL paths, so if it is found first it will be matched and render the routed component.

Within the `Switch` you should order the routes in descending order path specificity. If ordered correctly there is a near-zero need to use the `exact` prop. `${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars` is more specific than `${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken` is more specific than `${SPA_PREFIX}/cases`, and should be rendered in this order within the `Switch` component.

There should also be no other components between the `Switch` and `Route` or `Redirect` components for the exclusive route matching to work correctly.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars`}
    component={Sars}
  />
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} component={CaseView} />
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases`}>
    <CasesView />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/notifications`}>
    <NotificationsView />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/audit`}>
    <AuditView />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/settings`}>
    <SettingsView />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit how-do-you-write-nested-routes-after-dynamic-path-in-react-router-v5-2]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `exact` prop to the `Route` and wrapping the routes in a `switch` tag

```
<Switch>
{caseManagement
                      && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} exact component={CaseView} />}
                    {caseManagement
                      && <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases`}><CasesView /></Route>}
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/notifications`}><NotificationsView /></Route>
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/audit`}><AuditView /></Route>
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars`} component={Sars} /> 
                    <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/settings`}><SettingsView /></Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: This isn't the route I want. I want <Route path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken/sars`}><Sars /></Route> and when I add exact it's still ignored.

Comment: So, you need both routes, right? If you put the `exact` in the one without `/sars`, it will allow react-router to find another match (the one with `/sars`)

Comment: Just in case it this the docs related to your case https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: yea, I need both, but adding exact isn't working.

Comment: could you update the question with the code using `exact` that is not working?

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: @London804 can you try the edited answer?

Comment: It looks the same what did you change? Also, it doesn't work.

Comment: Added the `<Switch>` tag

Comment: The full code is wrapped in an <ErrorBoundary> and already has a switch statement

Comment: Got it, I'm out of ideas

Comment: I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `exact` prop to the `Route`

```
<Route exact path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/cases/:caseToken`} component={CaseView} />}
<Route exact path={`${SPA_PREFIX}/notifications`}><NotificationsView /></Route>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: can you tell us an example of what ```SPA_PREFIX``` value can be, does it start with a ```/``` ?

Comment: yes, it starts with a slash